# how to use Codable with Class enum

Tags: swift, codable

I feel like I'm going way too far for what should really be a simple thing. With the below code, the error that I get is: `Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(GameOfLife.Cell, forKey: GameOfLife.Cell.CodingKeys)'`

```
extension GameOfLife {
    enum Cell: Equatable, Codable {
        case alive
        case born
        case dying
        case dead

        var isAlive: Bool {
            switch self {
            case .alive, .born: return true
            case .dying, .dead: return false
            }
        }
        var isDead: Bool {
            switch self {
            case .alive, .born: return false
            case .dying, .dead: return true
            }
        }

        func equalTo(_ rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
            switch (self) {
            case .alive, .born:
                return rhs.isAlive
            case .dead, .dying:
                return rhs.isDead
            }
        }

        init(_ living: Bool) {
            self = living ? .alive : .dead
        }

        enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
            case alive
            case born
            case dying
            case dead
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            do {
                let leftValue = try container.decode(GameOfLife.Cell.alive, forKey: CodingKeys.alive)
                self = GameOfLife.Cell.alive
            } catch {
                let leftValue = try container.decode(GameOfLife.Cell.born, forKey: CodingKeys.born)
                self = GameOfLife.Cell.born
            } catch {
                let leftValue = try container.decode(GameOfLife.Cell.dying, forKey: CodingKeys.dying)
                self = GameOfLife.Cell.dying
            } catch {
                let leftValue = try container.decode(GameOfLife.Cell.dead, forKey: CodingKeys.dead)
                self = GameOfLife.Cell.dead
            }
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            switch self {
            case .alive:
                try container.encode("alive", forKey: .alive)
            case .born:
                try container.encode("born", forKey: .born)
            case .dying:
                try container.encode("dying", forKey: .dying)
            case .dead:
                try container.encode("dead", forKey: .dead)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `decode(` is the expected type of the decoded object. As you are encoding the enum cases a `String`, it's supposed to be `String`

```
let leftValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .alive) // The compiler can infer the type `CodingKeys`
```

However the entire `init(from` method makes no sense. If an error occurs inside a `catch` expression it is not going to be caught in the subsequent `catch` expression.

To encode an enum case as `String` just declare the raw type of the `enum` as `String` and delete the CodingKeys and the `init(from` and `encode(to` methods. And if you want to adopt Equatable you have to implement `==`

```
extension GameOfLife : Codable {

    enum Cell: String, Equatable, Codable {
        case alive, born, dying, dead

        var isAlive: Bool {
            switch self {
            case .alive, .born: return true
            case .dying, .dead: return false
            }
        }

        // isDead can be simplified
        var isDead: Bool {
            return !isAlive
        }

        static func == (lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
           switch (lhs.isAlive, rhs.isAlive) {
             case (true, true), (false, false): return true
             default: return false
           }
       }

        init(_ living: Bool) {
            self = living ? .alive : .dead
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the structure with the successive catches in init comes from this article: https://www.objc.io/blog/2018/01/23/codable-enums/ ". First, we try to decode using the .left key. If that doesn’t work, we catch the error, and try to decode using the .right key. If that doesn’t work either, the error will be propagated (just like a regular decoding error)"

Comment: The `init` method in the linked article has one `do` and **one** `catch` which is like *either - or* rather than your one `do` and three(!) `catch`

Comment: you're looking at the example _after_ the example that I followed. The example that I followed is **identical** to my approach